# Show JSON by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I show the JSON object that is in the random by clicking the button. With Javascript.

```
 var myObject = {
        "catalogo": [
            {
                "id" : "001",
                "name":"Nike",
                "desc" : "shoes",
                "price": 500,
            },
            {
                "id" : "002",
                "name":"MIKEY",
                "desc" : "shoes",
                "price": 500,
            },
            {
                "id" : "003",
                "name":"VANS",
                "desc" : "shoes",
                "price": 500,
            },
            {
                "id" : "004",
                "name":"SPORT",
                "desc" : "shoes",
                "price": 500,
            }
            ]
    };

var random = myObject.catalogo[Math.floor(Math.random()* myObject.catalogo.length)];
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = random.shortname + "<br>" + "$" + random.price + ".00";
```

HTML CODE:
Here is the code for the button to display the value.

```
    <div>
         <div id="random"></div>
         <button>Añadir</button>
   </div>
```

I want to show it here

```
<div>
    <p class="line"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your JS in a function and call it from your button with `onclick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is how you would do it.

> Take note, you also had some errors in your logic for getting the random data. The `table` ID doesn't exist (changed to `line`) and `shortname` isn't in your data (changed to `name`)

```js
var myObject = {
  "catalogo": [{
      "id": "001",
      "name": "Nike",
      "desc": "shoes",
      "price": 500,
    },
    {
      "id": "002",
      "name": "MIKEY",
      "desc": "shoes",
      "price": 500,
    },
    {
      "id": "003",
      "name": "VANS",
      "desc": "shoes",
      "price": 500,
    },
    {
      "id": "004",
      "name": "SPORT",
      "desc": "shoes",
      "price": 500,
    }
  ]
};

function showRandom() {

  var random = myObject.catalogo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myObject.catalogo.length)];
  
  document.querySelector('.line').innerHTML = random.name + "<br>" + "$" + random.price + ".00";

}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="random"></div>
  <button onclick="showRandom()">Añadir</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="line"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `button` to `<button id="anadir">Añadir</button>`.

After doing this, you can get your button from JS after the document loads:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var myAddButtton = document.getElementById('anadir');
  myAddButton.onclick = function() {
    var random = myObject.catalogo[
      Math.floor(Math.random()* myObject.catalogo.length)
    ];

    document.querySelector('.line')
      .innerHTML = random.shortname + "<br>" + "$" + random.price + ".00";
  }
}
```

Load this in a `<script>` tag in your page and it should work.